# vm,prank(address) not working as msg,sender in Foundry

Tags: testing, foundry

I have a function  in contract A given as->

```
function fun() public view returns (address) {
     return msg.sender;            
    }       
}
```

I was testing this function in foundry as->

```
  function test_fun()public returns{
         vm.prank(0x123);
         address Add= a.fun();    // a is instance of A in testing file
         emit log_address(Add);             
   }
```

but ***default_sender*** is being logged out.

I am not getting hy address **Add** is not emitted?

Please solve this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not an answer but you might find my [Foundry template](https://github.com/PaulRBerg/foundry-template) helpful.

Comment: Thank you for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare addresses when you create a test and use them later when you need them

```
contract MyContractTest is Test {
    MyContract public a;

    address owner = address(this);
    address user1 = vm.addr(1);
    address user2 = vm.addr(2);
    address user3 = vm.addr(3);
    address user4 = vm.addr(4);
...
    function test_fun()public returns{
         vm.prank(user1);
         address Add= a.fun();    // a is instance of A in testing file
         emit log_address(Add);             
    }
```

Remember that prank only switches the address for one next smart contract operation.
To execute multiple functions from one address use vm.startPrank(user1); and vm.stopPrank();

```
   function test_fun()public returns{
         vm.startPrank(user1);
         address Add= a.fun();    // a is instance of A in testing file
         emit log_address(Add);  
         vm.stopPrank();
   }
```

Comment: Hi Alexey Smirnov,
Thanks for your reply , but I have already tried these things which you have mentioned.                                                                                                                         I have used  **vm.startPrank()  & vm.stopPrank()** and                                                                                    declared address while creating testing file                                                                                    -> But then also I am getting same problem as stated above.

Comment: So the function is executed but emit fails?

Answer (score 0):

I think , I got an answer:

```
  address person1 = vm.addr(2);
  function test_fun()public returns{
     vm.startPrank(person1);
     address Add= a.fun();    // a is instance of A in testing file
     emit log_address(Add); 
     vm.stopPrank();            
   }
```

Whenever  during prank ,we call a function that requires `msg.sender` -> then our prank address will pass on as msg.sender.

```
 function fun() public view returns (address) {
 return msg.sender;            
}       
}
```

Thus It will return Person1's address .

But in case->

```
function test_prank() public{
vm.startPrank(person1);
emit log_address(msg.sender);vm
vm.stopPrank();    
 }
```

Here `default_sender`address will be emitted even though in during pranking as we have explicitly mentioned `msg.sender`